# Python processes started by Visual Studio Code when I open a Python file in the editor

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cython

I'm using Cython and I have a problem with some Python processes blocking the `*.pyd` files I want to build again after some editing. I report here my analysis before the question itself.

First of all, I open the task manager to check the situation and no Python process is running. Then I launch Visual Studio Code and I open my Python folder with no Python files yet opened in the editor's window. Still no Python process running.

At this point I open a `.pyx` file in the editor that is recognized as Python code (I've configured Visual Studio Code to do so, since I know I'm using Cython). At this point a few Python processes pop up in the task manager, likely because of internal Visual Studio Code's features like code analysis and so on.

Now, let's say that I've done my changes and, from my `venv`, I want to run:

```
python setup_mycode.py build_ext --inplace
```

which should be overwriting `mycode.pyd` but it is blocked by a lock on the file due to one of the above said Python processes. Closing all the open files in the editor is not enough to unlock it. The only two possibilities I have are:

- closing the whole folder from Visual Studio Code
- killing the Python process from the task manager

Is there a more elegant solution?

I've also researched the issues in Python extension github and found the [unloading/stop loading the extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9414) issue which has been closed in favor of an open feature request on VS Code (the latter generic feature request is not really what I'm asking here though: I may want to unload the extension at a certain point if it prevents me from building a Cython file but not to configure the workspace with that extension disabled since it is a Python folder and the extension would make sense when I am editing, disabling it in the first place would defeat the purpose of using Visual Studio Code instead of ,say, Notepad++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing and configuring [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) as default Language Server.

The relevant difference here is that, when opening a Python file in the editor, I see a few Python processes in the task manager that start and *terminate* by themselves *after a few seconds*.